# Azure DevOps import Git repositories requiring authorization via API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am able to import public Git repositories using the Azure DevOps API documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/import%20requests/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0).

However I am unable to handle repositories that require authorization with the same API.

I looked at the requests sent when using the UI and tried to reverse engineer by submitting various requests along these lines:

```
{
  "parameters": {
    "gitSource": {
      "url": "[URL]",
      "username": "[USERNAME]",
      "password": "[PASSWORD]"
    }
  }
}
```

...But nothing seems to work. There is no documentation on how to pass in authorization parameters for Git imports. I tried to mimic other calls that allow for this as well, to no avail.

Has anyone else tried this with any success or have any additional options I should attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is what I've been doing in my script:

```
# create endpoint
$endpoint = irm "$targetUrl/serviceendpoint/endpoints?api-version=5.0-preview" -Method:Post -ContentType "application/json" `
   -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"} `
   -Body ( '{{"name":"temporary-script-git-import","type":"git","url":"https://{3}@dev.azure.com/{3}/{0}/_git/{0}","authorization":{{"parameters":{{"username":"{1}","password":"{2}"}},"scheme":"UsernamePassword"}}}}' -f $sourceName, $username, $token, $organization )

# import repository
$importRepo = irm "$targetUrl/git/repositories/$sourceName/importRequests?api-version=5.0-preview" -Method:Post -ContentType "application/json" `
   -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"} `
   -Body ( '{{"parameters":{{"deleteServiceEndpointAfterImportIsDone":true,"gitSource":{{"url":"https://{2}@dev.azure.com/{2}/{0}/_git/{0}","overwrite":false}},"tfvcSource":null,"serviceEndpointId":"{1}"}}}}' -f $sourceName, $endpoint.id, $organization )
```

this would create a service endpoint to use to connect to git (in my case its Azure Devops but it would work with Github as well) and then its using that service endpoint to import the repo. $targetUrl - your Azure Devops path: `$targetUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$targetName/_apis"`

Comment: Hey , thanks for adding this piece.
Im having hard time with understanding how do i determine the target project for the import.

Lets say i want to import Git repo from ProjectA to ProjectB, in the same organization, using REST, how would you approach this ?

Many thanks

Comment: talk to projectA to get list of repos, talk to projectB to push needed repo from A to B